# Appending data to a subarray instead of having it overwritten with the latest entry

Tags: java

I currently have a Map that is configured as such.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
```

where the purpose is to be able to have a setup much like the following:

```
array("foo"->array(1->"aaa",2->"bbb",3->"ccc"),
      "bar"->array(1->"aaa",2->"bbb",3->"ccc"),
      "bah"->array(1->"aaa",2->"bbb",3->"ccc"),
)
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can create the root array fine, but it will do the following, using the previous example as illustration

```
array("foo"->array(3->"ccc"),
      "bar"->array(2->"bbb"),
      "bah"->array(3->"ccc"),
)
```

What I'm trying to find out is how I can append the sub array as opposed to having it overwritten. I assume it's easily done I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is to first check if map has an entry for a particular key. If not, then add an empty arraylist.

After that, get that arraylist from map and add object to that arraylist.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
    String first = "FIRST";
    if (map.get(first) == null){
        map.put(first, new ArrayList<Object>());
    }

    map.get(first).add(new Object());
```

If you will print above map, you will get desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a method to add to the sub-array, and create it if it doesn't exists :

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();
addToArray(map, "foo", "aaa");
addToArray(map, "foo", "bbb");
addToArray(map, "foo", "ccc");

addToArray(map, "bar", "aaa");
// ...
```

And the method would be :

```
private static void addToArray(final Map<String, ArrayList<Object>> map, final String key, final Object object) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key))
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<Object>());
    map.get(key).add(object);
}
```

If you only need to store Strings in you array, you can use an `ArrayList<String>` instead of your `ArrayList<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

Appending to Array's in Java is not possible because they have a fixed length. I suggest you use `ArrayList` instead.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Object>>();

public void appendToMap(String key, Object o)
{
    if(!map.containsKey(key))
    {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<Object>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(o);
}
```

Afterwards just set your values:

```
appendToMap("foo", "aaa");
appendToMap("foo", "bbb");
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `String` instead of `Object` *(if the list would always contain strings)*

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Then add to your `Map` as follows

```
// check if a List already exists
if ((list = map.get("foo")) == null) { // if !exists,

    list = new ArrayList<String>(1); // CREATE a new List
    list.add("aaa");
    map.put("foo", list); // ADD the new List to Map

} else { // if exists,
    list.add("aaa"); // ADD to the existing List
}
```